# How does the official Tomcat service determine the JVM on every start?

Tags: java, installation, jvm, tomcat6, inno-setup

I have a web application which runs on Tomcat 6 as a service. Both the application and Tomcat are installed with Inno Setup. What is the best way to set the JVM parameter?

I can determine the installed JVM from the registry and the tomcat6.exe (which installs the service) accepts the jvm parameter. But what if the user changes the jvm location? Or installs a newer JVM? How can I keep the JVM location dynamically?

The official Tomcat service (installed by Windows Service Installer) reads the registry for the JVM location on every start. But I can't use that installer, I have to install the service by the tomcat6.exe executable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you install the service with the .exe file, you give it params to run the service, like the classpath. There you can set the route to JVM as well. Check the .exe guide.

The only way to make it dynamic is to set it in a env. variable MY_JVM_PATH and use it in the service installation

Comment: I already set the jvm using those parameters: --Jvm='C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\j9vm\jvm.dll. My question is what can I do to prevent the application to stop when the jvm location changes.